# unable to connect to thingspeak/mqtt/esp32

Tags: mqtt, iot, publish-subscribe, esp32

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "Singh";
const char* password = "12345678";
const char* mqtt_server = "mqtt3.thingspeak.com";
const int mqtt_port = 1883;
const char* channel_id = "2322752";
const char* read_api_key = "GP5KY5DTF3RO3OEF";
const char* write_api_key = "OI7QW8PL9HSM7QX6";

WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(wifiClient);

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Received message on topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);
  Serial.print("Message: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  client.setServer(mqtt_server, mqtt_port);
  client.setCallback(callback);
  reconnect();
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }

  client.loop();

  // Generate a random value for Field 1
  float value1 = random(100) + 0.5; // Random float between 0.5 and 100.5

  // Construct the payload with the random value for Field 1
  char payload[50];
  snprintf(payload, sizeof(payload), "field1=%.2f", value1);

  // Construct the MQTT topic for publishing using Write API Key
  char write_topic[100];
  snprintf(write_topic, sizeof(write_topic), "channels/%s/publish/%s", channel_id, write_api_key);

  // Publish the payload
  client.publish(write_topic, payload);
  
  delay(10000);  // Publish data every 10 seconds
}

void reconnect() {
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    if (client.connect("ThingSpeakClient", read_api_key, "")) {
      Serial.println("Connected to MQTT server");
      char read_topic[100];
      snprintf(read_topic, sizeof(read_topic), "channels/%s/subscribe/fields/field3", channel_id);
      client.subscribe(read_topic);
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed to connect, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" Retrying in 1 second");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried multiple different hosts, "mqtt.thingspeak.com" with port 1883, "mqtt3.thingspeak.com" 1883 and "api.thingspeak.com" port 80, unable to connect with any of them

I can successfully connect when using thingspeak.h library but unable to do so using pubsubclient.h

serial monitor output: Attempting MQTT connection...

```
17:40:51.384 -> Failed to connect, rc=-2 Retrying in 1 second'
```

Comment: Please confirm you can connect using something like [`mosquitto_pub`](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_pub-1.html) using the credentials you are using in your esp32 code (best to ensure those details are correct before trying to find issues in your code).

Comment: ThingSpeak requires username and password for connecting to the broker `mqttClient.connect( clientID, mqttUserName, mqttPass )` and you are not doing any of that.